# Compute the value of integral $A(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> A function $f$, continuous on the positive axis, has the property that for all choices of $x>0$ and $y>0$, the integral 
>   $$
> \int_{x}^{xy} f(t)\,dt
> $$
>   is independent of $x$ (and therefore depends only on $y$). If $f(2)=2$, compute the value of the integral
>   $$
> A(x)= \int_{1}^{x} f(t)\,dt
> $$
>   for all $x>0$.

I am trying to prove the linearity, but I'm not sure whether this approach is right or not.

One substitution which I attempted was $u=t/x$. But I couldn't reach the desired result using this.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$. Then, by assumption,
$$
\int_{x}^{xy}f(t)\,dt=F(xy)-F(x)
$$
doesn't depend on $x$, so its derivative with respect to $x$ is $0$. The derivative computes as
$$
F'(xy)y-F'(x)=f(xy)y-f(x)
$$
and so you have that, for every $x,y>0$,
$$
f(x)=f(xy)y
$$
Now choose $y=2/x$ and finish up:

> $$f(x)=f(2)\cdot\frac{2}{x}=\frac{4}{x}$$

Comment: Oh. Nice. This didn't occur to me.  Is this problem easy ?

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$F(y):=\int_x^{xy} f(t)\>dt\qquad (x>0, \> y>0)\ .$$ 
Then
$$F'(y)=f(xy)\cdot x\ .$$
Letting $y:=1$ here we obtain
$f(x)={F'(1)\over x}$, and as $f(2)=2$ it follows definitively that
$$f(x)={4\over x}\ .$$
I may leave $A(x)$ to you.

Comment: Thanks.............